# RecyclerView corrupts view using notifyItemMoved()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem with using the `notifyItemMoved()` method. It seems to be incorrectly displaying unmoved views.

My list has 4 element in it. What I want to do is animate a swap between item 1 and item 3. Items 1 and 3 swap correctly, but item 2 displays what was at item 3!

So the list starts off looking something like this:

```
Item 0
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

And ends like this:

```
Item 0
Item 3
Item 3 <-- What the heck has this changed for?
Item 1
```

My adapter is backed by a `List mProductList`. I call the following code:

```
public void sortBackingListUsingSortingList(List<ProductWrapper> newProductItems) {
    Log.e("", "Before:");
    for(ProductWrapper wrapper : mProductItems) wrapper.log();
    for(int i = 0; i < newProductItems.size(); i++) {
        ProductWrapper currentItem   = mProductItems.get(i);
        ProductWrapper correctItem   = newProductItems.get(i);

        if(!currentItem.equals(correctItem)) {
            // Item in wrong place
            int indexOfCorrectItem = getIndexOfItemInList(mProductItems, correctItem);
            Collections.swap(mProductItems, i, indexOfCorrectItem);
            notifyItemMoved(i, indexOfCorrectItem);
            Log.e("", "notifyItemMoved(" + i + ", " + indexOfCorrectItem+")");
            Log.e("", "After:");
            for(ProductWrapper wrapper : mProductItems) wrapper.log();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also added logging to `onBindViewHolder` to check if my view logic is being called:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HolderBasic holder, int position) {
    Log.e("", "onBindViewHolder(holder, " + position + ")");
    holder.fill(mProductItems.get(position));
}
```

My logs look like this:

```
09-02 14:39:17.853: Before:
09-02 14:39:17.853: Item 0
09-02 14:39:17.853: Item 1
09-02 14:39:17.853: Item 2
09-02 14:39:17.853: Item 3

09-02 14:39:17.854: notifyItemMoved(1, 3)

09-02 14:39:17.854: After:
09-02 14:39:17.854: Item 0
09-02 14:39:17.854: Item 3
09-02 14:39:17.854: Item 2
09-02 14:39:17.854: Item 1

09-02 14:39:17.867: onBindViewHolder(holder, 1)
09-02 14:39:17.874: onBindViewHolder(holder, 3)
```

As you can see, no reason for Item 2 to have change it's display at all - and yet, it does. Anybody know why?

**EDIT**

I can get around above by looping through the entire adapter and calling `notifyItemChanged()` on every item. Inefficient and not a good solution, but is invisible to the user.

Comment: So, I think you are saying that `onBindViewHolder(holder, 1)` should not be called, right? I also don't know why it *is* called... But I also think that you should just call `notifyItemChanged(i); notifyItemChanged(indexOfCorrectItem);` instead of `notifyItemMoved(i, indexOfCorrectItem);` Have you tried that?

Comment: No, the problem is that item 2 is changing it's display. onBindViewHolder should be called for 1 and 3 because notifyItemMoved(1, 3) marks both of them as needing to be redrawn. What shouldn't happen is Item 2 be involved in any way, it shouldn't be touched.

Comment: I don't know why the RecyclerView is behaving the exact way it is, but I *can* understand that it is confused by what you are doing: You started with `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. By calling `notifyItemChanged(1, 3)` you are saying: "I have removed the item position 1 inserted it at position 3". For this to be true your list should now be `[0, 2, 3, 1]`. But it actually is `[0, 3, 2, 1]`, so if it then calls `onBindViewHolder(holder, 1)` *of course* it is going to see the `3` there and overwrite the `2` that was there before. What puzzles me is only that it feels the need to even call that...

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to just call `notifyItemChanged(i); notifyItemChanged(indexOfCorrectItem);` instead of looping over the whole adapter?

Comment: david - you led me to the answer, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thank you to @david.mihola for leading me to what I'm doing wrong.

This took so long to figure out as the symptom didn't make the problem obvious!

I was doing this:

```
Collections.swap(mProductItems, i, indexOfCorrectItem);
notifyItemMoved(i, indexOfCorrectItem)
```

But, I obviously didn't think through what `notifyItemMoved()` was actually doing. It is only notifying the adapter that item `i` has moved to `indexOfCorrectItem` **it isn't telling the adapter that `indexOfCorrectItem` has also moved to `i`**.

Under the covers it was doing the following:

1. Move item 1 to 3
2. Move what was at 2 to 1 to fill the gap
3. Move what was at 3 to 2 to fill the gap
4. `notifyItemChanged(1);`
5. `notifyItemChanged(3);`

The above of course leaves item 3 moved down to item 2 without a refreshed view! It was steps 4 and 5 which were hiding the problem by making item1 and item3 display correctly and leaving item2 incorrect!

As soon as I realised this I tried the following code:

```
notifyItemMoved(indexOfCorrectItem, i);
notifyItemMoved(i, indexOfCorrectItem);
```

This left the list in the correct order, but it short circuited the animation.

So, instead, I dumped swapping altogether:

```
mProductItems.remove(indexOfCorrectItem);
mProductItems.add(i, correctItem);
notifyItemMoved(indexOfCorrectItem, i);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation: Have you looked into the RecyclerView code enough to understand why notifyItemChanged(1) was called at all (your step 4)? If you tell the adapter "Item 1 is removed, so slide Item 2 down one slot" it should not need to rebind that item at all. At least not any more than it would subsequently need to rebind the next item...

Comment: I found that using

    `Collections.swap(dataSet, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(toPosition);`

kept both the animations, and updated any incorrect view holder bindings that utilized old position values

Comment: I just had a similar issue when trying to update values of the items. My recyclerview was showing duplicate/corrompted items while the adapter had the correct information, so the problem was in the recyclerview, not the adapter. I had to do the same as @Graeme. Thank you.  item.setCantidad(item.getCantidad() + newItem.getCantidad());
            mitems.remove(position);
            mitems.add(item);
            notifyItemMoved(position, mitems.size() - 1);
            notifyItemChanged(mitems.size() - 1);

Comment: I confirm, doing as Graeme, when I do as @saganaut says, I got corrompted items on my recyclerview but (the adapter items are always correct).

Comment: @Herman - I would wager that our use cases differ.  In my instance, drag-and-drop functionality was causing view holder elements to retain onClick bindings that utilize position values - these position values were incorrect after the drag and drop happened.  The solution I posted solved this for me.

Comment: @Graeme Do you know how to save the swaped position ?
I have tried with `notifyItemChanged` and added the position there but when I exit the app and again open the list it is back to normal.

Comment: @CarterHudson Thank you! Your solution works fine. But still small issue occur when user move item super fast (It is about testing but normal user might not do so).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. RecyclerView-Items are corrupt on drag&drop. But I have found a simple solution:
In your RecyclerView.Adapter.class be sure to have the following

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // here code for getting the right itemID, 
    // i.e. return super.getItemId(mPosition);
    // where mPosition ist the Position in the Collection.
}
```

You must return the right itemID for the position. From now on the Items are not corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I actually handled it differently too, with my way, the animation will stay the same and you won't have any trouble of items at wrong positions anymore :

```
@Override
public void onRowMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(listOfItem, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(listOfItem, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}
```

With this, you can reorder items without any issues

[Tutorial used to fix my issue](https://www.journaldev.com/23208/android-recyclerview-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me, but I see a very slight jitter in animation. In case if there is a better solution do let me know :)

```
 public void moveItem(int oldPos, int newPos) {
    Uri item = mDataSet.get(oldPos);
    mDataSet.remove(oldPos);
    mDataSet.add(newPos, item);
    notifyItemMoved(oldPos, newPos);

    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mDataSet.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual position of your item after a drag&drop, add this method to your adapter:

```
private int getItemPosition(Item item){ // (<-- replace with your item)
    int i = 0;
    // (replace with your items and methods here)
    for (Item currentItem : mItems) {
        if (currentItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId()) break;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

and call this instead of the position given by the viewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I handled it in a slightly different way, might help others.

```
        Collections.swap(mItemList, fromPosition, toPosition);
        // Need to do below, because NotifyItemMove only handle one sided move
        Item fromItem = mItemList.get(fromPosition);
        Item toItem = mItemList.get(toPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(fromPosition, toItem);
        notifyItemChanged(toPosition, fromItem);
```

I had to reorder items on a grid, and save the positions to a file. 
@Graeme was right, but i didn't wanted to give up on swapping. So just like @saganaut i sticked to notifyItemChanged. But only using notifyItemChanged sometimes left both swapped items on my grid with same items, so I binded the items with notifyItemChanged. It is not killing the animation, and is working as expected.