# Push RecyclerView item to the top without modifying other items orders

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have 5 items in my `RecyclerView` (initial state):

- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3
- Product 4
- Product 5

If one product is featured, I show a simple animation and I push the product to top of the `RecyclerView`. For example, if the Product 4 is featured, then the orders become:

- Product 4
- Product 2
- Product 3
- Product 1
- Product 5

I want to push the item to the top of the `RecyclerView` without modifying the order of other items like the following.

- Product 4
- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3
- Product 5

Here's the function that I have.

```
private void pushSelectedProductToTop(final int selectedProductPosition) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Collections.swap(currentProductListResponseRecyclerView.getProducts(), selectedProductPosition, 0);
        productsAdapter.notifyItemMoved(selectedProductPosition, 0);
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354917/recyclerview-corrupts-view-using-notifyitemmoved

Comment: You might just call `productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @ALTegani: exactly what I was looking for `mProductItems.remove(indexOfCorrectItem);
mProductItems.add(i, correctItem);
notifyItemMoved(indexOfCorrectItem, i);`

Comment: good news ...happy for you @MohamedElloumi

Answer (score 1):

You want to move "Product 4" to the top of the list. Do this: Remove "Product 4" (position == 3) using `remove`. See [`remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)). Then insert the item at position 0 using `add`. See [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)).

You can then call `productsAdapter.notifyItemMoved(selectedProductPosition, 0)`.