# why recycler view items are not rearranging?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recycler view and there are items in it. Now I am using bubble sorting to rearrange them. But `adapter.notifyItemMoved` doesn't work properly in the loop (it is slow). Please look at the code below and help, I have added comments to make u understand. One more thing, I can't sort the list in beginning before adapting. So please don't put that as a solution. I know that this is a solution but that will not work in my case.

```
//rv_all is a recycler view
for (i in 0 until rv_all.childCount)
{
    for (j in 0 until rv_all.childCount - 1)
    {
        /* i have added tag while binding in ViewHolder
         itemView.stdate.tag = "date" */
        val date1 =
            sdf.parse(rv_all.getChildAt(j).findViewWithTag < TextView("date").text.toString())
        val date2 =
            sdf.parse(rv_all.getChildAt(j + 1).findViewWithTag < TextView("date").text.toString())
        if (date1 != null && date2 != null)
        {
            if (date1.before(date2))
            {
                //alllist is a list used to adapt to recycler view
                Collections.swap(alllist, j, j + 1)
                alladapter.notifyItemMoved(j, j + 1)
                // problem is here ,it is working fine when not in a loop but in loop it is doing nothing
                // i have debugged and used breakpoints and what i saw that alllist is swapping elements but adapter child are not rearranging
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this loop? Does it get executed?

Comment: yes it executes.

Comment: You could re-asign the list then set it to the the adapter and in the Adapter Class in the set part you call notifyDataSetChanged() this will refresh the whole RecyclerView.

Comment: Thnxx for the solution(SO is full of geniuses). I got the point, But also i want to know what was wrong in my piece of code.

Comment: I guess you are executing the notifyItemMoved to fast so the adapter does not recognize all changes. notfiyItemMoved is more for changing one item position, not looping it. But this is just a presumption.

Comment: yup same thing i was assuming. Thanks once gain

Comment: Check this answer, I think you're doing the same mistake: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357294/1101730

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating through childrens of `RecyclerView` (why twice? you arent using `i` anywhere, this is unefficient)

```
for (i in 0 until rv_all.childCount) {
    for (j in 0 until rv_all.childCount - 1) {
```

but these are only `View`s - first child/`View` is at position 0, second 1 etc. When you scroll a bit down and your `RecyclerView` first visible item is e.g. 10th in `alllist`, then still first visible `View` is at position 0, like always

thus these lines makes no sense:

```
Collections.swap(alllist,j,j+1)
alladapter.notifyItemMoved(j,j+1)
```

they always swapping and notifying items at the beggining of array, starting 0, but your `RecyclerView` can be scrolled a bit down to e.g. 10th item - then above lines are swapping items in `alllist`, but `notifyItemMoved` does nothing as `RecyclerView` doesn't have to redraw first items, they are "scrolled out"

so in short: position of `View` drawn in `RecyclerView` != position in data array

you can add "real_position" tag in adapter to every child, then you can still iterate through visible childs/`View`s, obtain `View`s with `findViewByTag`, but `swap` and `notifyItemMoved` for positions in data array ("real_position" obtained from tag), not visible childs positions in parent `RecyclerView`

```
var realPosition : Integer = rv_all.getChildAt(j).tag as Integer // set in adapter
Collections.swap(alllist, realPosition, realPosition+1)
alladapter.notifyItemMoved(realPosition, realPosition+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using notifyDataSetChanged():

```
class MovieAdapter(...) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieViewHolder>() {

var data: List<Movies> = list
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
...
```

For a more effient way of refreshing use  DiffUtil.ItemCallback<...>(). See the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.ItemCallback)