# Moving item in RecyclerView doubles item in view

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, move

I'm building a contact list (ArrayList) in a messaging app using RecyclerView.

When a contact updates, I want to move that user to the top of the list, while all other items in the list move one step down.

I'm using Firestore to get the list of users.

```
DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {
                        val matchThatChanged = dc.newIndex
                        
                        matchesArrayList[matchThatChanged] = ChatMatchListMatch(
                            matchUserID)

                        adapter.notifyItemChanged(matchThatChanged) //Ensures change is visible immediately

                        val fromPosition = matchesArrayList.indexOfFirst {
                            it!!.matchUserID == matchUserID
                        }

                        
                        Log.d(TAG, "From position A: $matchThatChanged")

                        if (fromPosition != 0) {
                            adapter.moveMatchToTop(
                                fromPosition, ChatMatchListMatch(
                                    matchUserID
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
```

In the Log here it correctly outputs 1 when I make the first move. However, thereafter it outputs 0 when I try to update the other user? This is not correct. The user that gets pushed down should no longer be at 0, it should be at 1. Because it is now wrongly at 0, it is not running the code (this is not the issue. The issue is that is should not be 0 in the first place).

Here's the code in my adapter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.chat_matchlist_item, parent, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(view)
}

// Passes the ContactListMatch object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val contactListMatch = mMatchesArrayList[position]
    (holder as CustomViewHolder).bind(contactListMatch)
}

fun moveMatchToTop(fromPosition: Int, chatMatchListMatch: ChatMatchListMatch) {
    mMatchesArrayList.removeAt(fromPosition)
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition)
    notifyItemRemoved(fromPosition)
    mMatchesArrayList.add(0, chatMatchListMatch)
    notifyItemInserted(0)
    notifyItemChanged(0)
    notifyItemChanged(1)
   
}
```

The list I have to begin with is:

[image]

When I update only the bottom user (2), it displays correctly (moving user two to the top and the other user down):

[image]

I now try to update original user 1 again, and I expect it to go on top again, like this:

[image]

But instead I get this:

[image]

Comment: Whre is the code? How can we help you?

Comment: @emandt The code is there. It's just three lines. Help me solve the problem.

Comment: You forgot to call "notifyDataSetChanged()" and/or just "notifyItemChanged(fromPosition); notifyItemChanged(toPosition);"

Comment: @emandt that doesn't work. Problem persists. I'm also wondering if using the Collections.swap method is wrong, since I don't want to just swap items. I want to move the updated item to the top and move all other items down one spot.

Comment: If your goal is that, then swap() is not the right way. Why not just "remove();" and do "add(0, ...);"? Then "notifyDataSetChanged()".

Comment: Jupp, I tried that too now, but it doesn't work. Same problem persists. It's like it understand it needs to add the match to the new spot. But it doesn't understand that this other match needs to be moved down.

Comment: Again: without view more pieces of code (especially onBindViewHolder() and onCreateViewHolder()) it's difficult to help you... Try read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354917/recyclerview-corrupts-view-using-notifyitemmoved

Comment: @emandt I still can't figure it out, so I have added code. Can you take a look?

Comment: Your `moveMatchToTop` looks suspicious.  Why are you removing the item, saying it changed, _then_ saying it was removed?  Just say it was removed.  The item changed calls in the latter part look unnecessary too.

Comment: That said, this really is going to be hard to offer any more than guesses without a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I had to make several changes, but I'll try to make this helpful to others who may struggle with similar issues:

I used an index in Firestore and used two "orderby" queries to get the list in the order I wanted:

```
myCollectionRef
        .orderBy("unread", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener
```

Then under case MODIFIED:

```
DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {
```

I had to get the old index and the new index of the item changed. When I get the old index (by iterating through my list to look for it with a for loop), I ensure to remove the item from the list and notify my adapter that I removed the item:

```
val newIndex = dc.newIndex

var oldIndex = -1
for (i in myList.indices.reversed()) {
     if (myList[i]!!.IDnumber == userID) {
          oldIndex = i                                                                   
          myList.removeAt(oldIndex)
          adapter.notifyItemRemoved(oldIndex)
          }
     }
```

Then I have to add the changed item back into my list in the correct position. Since I have the new index, this is easy. I also notify my adapter of the change:

```
myList.add(
     newIndex, MySpecialItem(
          userID!!,
          userImageOrWhatever!!
          )
     )
                        
 adapter.notifyItemInserted(newIndex)
```

and that's it.